# Curl scripts in Android

Tags: java, android, curl

I have been provided several curl commands that to use in android.

The curl commands are structured like this:

```
curl "https://www.website.com/api/a/page" 
  -H "Authorization: Bearer API_KEY"
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -X GET
```

I can not figure out how to make use of this in java in Android.

If it could be turned into something like:

```
stringURL = "https://www.website.com/api/a/page&appid=API_KEY";
URL url = new URL(stringURL);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of code reusability, and for conforming to the preferred Android patterns (e.g., MVVM), it is generally accepted practice to use an HTTP library such as [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). If your case is simple enough, you should be able to map your cURL parameters to the Retrofit  classes and methods easily enough.

Other options include [Apache HTTPComponents Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/index.html), [OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/), [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), [JettyHttpClient](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http-client.html), and so on.

If you wish, you can always use the core Java `HttpUrlConnection` as you've included in the example. However, it is good practice to wrap these functions/methods into appropriate classes, interfaces, callbacks, or repositories, as required. (The available libraries manage this overhead for you.)

If I've not addressed some specific concerns, let me know so that I can build on this answer further.

**P.S.**: Not including any code here, since the link to any of the docs should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the curl commands to postman via Import > Paste raw
- Export postman collection
- Install this plugin [PostmanToRetrofit2](https://github.com/ShuYiBin/PostmanToRetrofit2)
- <kbd>Right click</kbd>  > <kbd>Generate</kbd> > <kbd>Retrofit2Generator</kbd> > Paste your postman collection > <kbd>OK</kbd>